# How do I pronounce "yod" when there is a dot inside of it?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, vowels-nekudot

I'm trying to brush up on my Hebrew. As an American Jew, it is still important to me to be able to recite my prayers from the siddur in their original Hebrew.

How do I pronounce "yod" when there is a dot inside of it? Here's how it appeared in my most recent Hebrew lesson: ׁׁׁׁשִיֵּץ

Comment: It's just like a regular "yod" only you [geminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) it.

Comment: @chay usually a letter with a dot is pronounced with the letter proceding it.

Comment: Chaya, Quizlet.com addresses this issue. Check out the following:  quizlet.com/.../chapter-2-consonantal-and-vocalic-yodvav-rules-flash-cards...

Comment: Definitely off-topic, but welcome. In case you overlooked it, you also have a dot (known as a "dagesh") in the Yud in your name.

Comment: @msh210 I maintain my off topic vote, as it seems does R' SethJ

Comment: @DoubleAA shouldn't your first comment be an answer?

Comment: @avi The question at the time was closed, and [I maintain it should still be](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34172/how-do-i-pronounce-yod-when-there-is-a-dot-inside-of-it?noredirect=1#comment87695_34172).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I apologize for the off-topicness. Being new, I'll have to work a little harder. I've been following this site for a long time and wanted to begin participating. After reading the forum rules, I would assume now that a discussion about י regarding the implications of its position within The Name, for example, might be more on topic?

Comment: @chayaחַיָּה it's mostly offtopic because of the desire for the Hebrew SE. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage
But if the implication you are asking about is not grammatical it should be on topic.

Comment: @avi No! The question is on-topic if and only if it has to do with Judaism, regardless of whether there's a Hebrew SE or a desire for one. Now that chaya has edited it to make it explicitly about the proper pronunciation of Jewish prayer, which is undeniably a requirement of Judaism, the fact that it has to do with Hebrew grammar does *nothing* to make it off-topic.

Comment: @IsaacMoses It has nothing to do with Jewish prayer. She wants to get better at Jewish prayer. That doesn't mean the question is about Jewish prayer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, In what non-Judaism context would anyone care about pronouncing a dagesh chazak? Are they even printed in non-Judaism contexts?

Comment: @IsaacMoses A) She doesn't know that. B) If you are in linguistics/grammar school or various kinds of academia or if you are a nerd. It really doesn't matter. C) Depends how formal and/or beginner-level the writing is.

Comment: @DoubleAA A) The context for this question is set in the first paragraph. Would you feel differently if "in reciting prayers" was added explicitly before the question mark?

Comment: @DoubleAA What is it that I "don't know"? I didn't know you were able to watch me davening... :)

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/23585237?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 8):

*Yod*, like most other letters, can only get a dot in it called a "*[dagesh chazak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagesh#Dagesh_hazak)*." This indicates that the affected consonant should be [geminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination), or doubled the way [you would double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination#English), e.g. the 'b' sound in "subbasement."

So, for the word in your example, שִיֵּץ, you would say "shiy-yatz" rather than "shiyatz," and your name would be pronounced "Chay-ya" rather than "Chaya."

Congratulations on your intention and efforts toward pronouncing prayers correctly! If you can incorporate this detail of correct pronunciation into your habits, you'll be taking a big step toward exceptionally precise pronunciation

Comment: This is something I've been working on of late (and is a good suggestion regarding your question about improving concentration during davening)